# Ubuntu 13.04 on Windows 8 with dual boot

Tags: installation, 13.04, partitioning, windows-8

I want to install Ubuntu 13.04 on Windows 8 with dual boot.

What is recommended swap size in terms of total size given to ubuntu (i want to give 500 G for ubuntu)?

Is 10 - 20 % of total ubuntu partition sufficient?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The size of swap space is best determined by the amount of RAM you have, not by your total disk space. The usual recommendation is to make swap space 1-2x your available RAM. The main reason for this is so that you can use the suspend-to-disk feature of the OS; when using this feature, RAM is copied to swap space, so swap space needs to be at least as large as your RAM. On most modern computers, swap is seldom used aside from this feature, so some users who don't use suspend-to-disk prefer to do without swap; however, I prefer to create it, since it gives you some insurance in case your memory use temporarily increases beyond normal limits.

Comment: Thanks for the solution. After confirming the recommended swap usage I tried to install Ubuntu but I am unable to do so.Link to other question is [link](http://askubuntu.com/questions/317869/installation-hangs-while-installing-ubuntu-13-04-on-preinstalled-windows-8)