# Installation Hangs while installing ubuntu 13.04 on preinstalled windows 8

Tags: installation, 13.04, windows-8

I am trying to install ubuntu 13.04(64 bits) along side windows 8,vaio. When I boot from USB it asks me option to "install ubuntu". But when I select it then installation hangs, blank screen. I have already taken following steps

1. Disable secure boot
2. Disable fast start up
3. Turn of windows defender
4. Created separate unallocated disc space for ubuntu

Can any one help me with this.

Comment: try this - [My computer boots to a black screen, what options do I have to fix it?](http://askubuntu.com/q/162075)

Comment: In the boot parameters,I have tried various options. I have replaced quiet splash with
1. nomedeset
2. acpi=off
3. nolapic

but nothing seems to work. 

I have AMD grpahics.

Answer (score 0):

try this website http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/tired-of-windows-8-how-to-dual-boot-windows-ubuntu/ I think you are getting this problem because of BIOS and as I remember you should use UEFI to dual boot win 8(I guess) but following the above mentioned guide the exact problem was solved on my brothers laptop

Comment: It is better to summarize the contents of any link you post so that the asker can solve his/her problem without following external links.